Methods returning a reference and trait implementation in Rust
Question rust returning a reference to a integer from a function was tagged as duplicate, and almost is.
The question Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable? was referenced, suggesting that &42 were static.
However, code (playground)
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Curse<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for Curse<T> {
    type Target = usize;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &<Self as Deref>::Target {
        &42 // wat
    }
   
}

fn main() {
    let a = 123;
    let c = *{
        let b = Curse(a);
        b.deref()
    };
    
    println!("{a} {c}");
}


will result in:
Exited with status 101

Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
17 |         let b = Curse(a);
   |             - binding `b` declared here
18 |         b.deref()
   |         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
19 |     };
   |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error

Standard Output


Edit:
By the way, as is mentionned in comment, following code compiles and runs with same results:
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Curse<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for Curse<T> {
    type Target = usize;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &'static <Self as Deref>::Target {
        &42 // wat
    }
   
}

fn main() {
    let a = 123;
    let c = *{
        let b = Curse(a);
        b.deref()
    };
    
    println!("{a} {c}");
}

Questions:
Is the lifetime of 42 bound by the lifetime of &self (and is it put on stack?) or is it internally static?
Why is the trait implementation with mismatching signature allowed?

Edit:
Explanations are found in comments with links to refined trait implementations.

You have &'static 42 but when returned from the function the lifetime is shortened to that of &self in order to satisfy its signature.  I don't think Rust makes any guarantees over where the 42 is located in memory (chances are it'll compile down to an immediate or be stored in a register); within the abstract machine, it's still in static memory, however.

Lifetimes are part of the public interface of a function, and the public interface is defined by the signature. The function signature either includes explicit lifetime annotations, or lifetime elision rules are applied. It would be bad if you had to read the function body to understand the lifetime of the return value.

@SvenMarnach, the behavior does not change though when you use &'static <Self as Deref>::Target as the return type of deref.

@hkBst I'm not sure what's happening in that case. In my opinion, compilation should fail because the function signature in the implementation differs from the signature in the trait, but for some reason the compiler doesn't complain about that. I don't have time to investigate.

@hkBst I asked the experts, and it turns out that the compiler allows relaxing the lifetime bounds in trait implementations, consumers of the trait don't get to benefit from the "refinements" and are still bound by the more restrictive lifetime bounds in the trait definition. So for a proper test you'd need to define a new trait with a &'static return value right in the trait definition.

The digressions in the comments are far more interesting than the question itself. The question should be rewritten, although I'm not sure how to do that without it sounding contrived.
